Map JSON column to both string and strongly-typed data with EF Core
An entity:
public class Person
{
  // both of these properties should refer to same jsonb column
  public string ContactsJson { get; }
  public Contacts Contacts { get; }
}

public class Contacts
{
  public string Tel { get; }
  public string Fax { get; }
}

One can map a JSON column to a string:
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
  .Property(x => x.ContactsJson)
  .HasColumnType("jsonb")
  .IsRequired();

One can map a JSON column to strongly-typed data:
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
  .OwnsOne(x => x.Contacts, b => {
    b.ToJson();
    b.Property(c => c.Tel).IsRequired();
    b.Property(c => c.Fax).IsRequired(false);
  });

If one uses both of those snippets then obviously EF will create two columns. But I want just one jsonb column, Contacts, which is mapped to both a string and strongly-typed data.
How do I do that?
Also, I assume having two properties refer to the same column can cause issues if I update one property and not the other. How does one deal with that scenario?
UPDATE:
As per advice on the repo: "define an updatable view over the table which adds the virtual column, and then tell EF to map to that view instead".
How can I do that with EF Core 8 and postgres?

Since there's no answer (so far), I also posted on the repo.

How can I do that? by reading the SQL Server documentation on creating views.

@IanKemp Many thanks, Ian.
